# Prove that all sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Prove that all sylow $p$-subgroups are conjugate

I have read other proofs that make sense to me. Here was one proof our professor showed in the lecture, but I am stuck on it.

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H, K$ be two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$. Let $\Lambda=G/H$ be the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. Let $G$ act on $\Lambda$ by left multiplication and so does $K$. I know it will be sufficient if we can show that there exists a coset $gH$ s.t. $KgH\subset gH$.

However, I have trouble showing it. The hint he gave us was to use the fact that the size of $K$ is a power of $p$.

How am I supposed to use the hint?

Comment: Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, given that you are acting with a $p$-group on a set that has relative-to-$p$ elements.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for Arturo's hint. I solve the question.

**Claim**: Let $G$ be a $p$-group and $S$ be a set. Let $G$ act on $S$ and denote the stable elements as $S^G=\{s\in S:\forall g\in G, gs=s\}$. Then $|S|\equiv |S^G|\pmod{p}$.

The proof of the claim follows exactly from OSF. $|S|=\sum_{x} Orb(x)=\sum_x\frac{|G|}{Stab(x)}$ where $x$ is the representative in each orbit. Since $Stab(x)$ is a subgroup of $G$, then we must have $|Orb(x)|=1$ or $p||Orb(x)|$. Since $|Orb(x)|=1$ if and only if $x\in S^G$, then we are done.

For my question, since $G/H,p$ are coprime then there must be one non-identity element in $\Lambda^G$, that is, there exists one $gH$ s.t. $KgH=gH$.